# using eval in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of eval in a data.table as a "frame".

With following data.table:

```
set.seed(1)
foo = data.table(var1=sample(1:3,1000,r=T), var2=rnorm(1000),  var3=sample(letters[1:5],1000,replace = T))
```

I'm trying to replicate this instruction

```
foo[var1==1 , sum(var2) , by=var3]
```

using a function of eval:

```
eval1 = function(s) eval( parse(text=s) ,envir=sys.parent() )
```

As you can see, test 1 and 3 are working, but I don't understand  which is the "correct" envir to set in eval for test 2:

```
var_i="var1"
var_j="var2"
var_by="var3"

# test 1 works
foo[eval1(var_i)==1 , sum(var2) , by=var3 ]

# test 2 doesn't work
foo[var1==1 , sum(eval1(var_j)) , by=var3]

# test 3 works
foo[var1==1 , sum(var2) , by=eval1(var_by)]
```

Comment: This seems to work `v1 <- parse(text=paste(var_i, "==", 1));
v2 <- parse(text=paste0("sum(", var_j, ", na.rm = TRUE)")); by1 <- parse(text=var_by); f1 <- function(dt, expr1, expr2, expr3){
 dt[eval(expr1), eval(expr2), by=eval(expr3)]
 }; f1(foo, v1, v2, by1)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, it works but it isn't what I'm looking for. I would try (if possible) to understand the frame of the data.table in the j expression ( DT[i,j,by] ). Thanks again, hope my question is clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `j-exp`, checks for it's variables in the environment of `.SD`, which stands for `Subset of Data`. `.SD` is itself a `data.table` that holds the columns for *that group*.

When you do:

```
foo[var1 == 1, sum(eval(parse(text=var_j))), by=var3]
```

directly, the `j-exp` gets internally optimised/replaced to `sum(var2)`. But `sum(eval1(var_j))` doesn't get optimised, and stays as it is.

Then when it gets evaluated for each group, it'll have to find `var2`, which doesn't exist in the parent.frame() from where the function is called, but in `.SD`. As an example, let's do this:

```
eval1 <- function(s) eval(parse(text=s), envir=parent.frame())
foo[var1 == 1, { var2 = 1L; eval1(var_j) }, by=var3]
#    var3 V1
# 1:    e  1
# 2:    c  1
# 3:    a  1
# 4:    b  1
# 5:    d  1
```

It find `var2` from it's parent frame. That is, we have to point to the right environment to evaluate in, with an additional argument with value = `.SD`.

```
eval1 <- function(s, env) eval(parse(text=s), envir = env, enclos = parent.frame())
foo[var1 == 1, sum(eval1(var_j, .SD)), by=var3]
#    var3         V1
# 1:    e  11.178035
# 2:    c -12.236446
# 3:    a  -8.984715
# 4:    b  -2.739386
# 5:    d  -1.159506
```