# data.table .. notation with functions in j

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to use data.table's `..` notation with functions, here is the code I have so far:

```
set.seed(42)
dt <- data.table(
  x = rnorm(10),
  y = runif(10)
)

test_func <- function(data, var, var2) {
  vars <- c(var, var2)
  data[, ..vars]
}

test_func(dt, 'x', 'y') # this works

test_func2 <- function(data, var, var2) {
  data[, ..var]
}

test_func2(dt, 'x', 'y') # this works too

test_func3 <- function(data, var, var2) {
  data[, sum(..var)]
}

test_func3(dt, 'x', 'y') 
# this does not work
# Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : object '..var' not found
```

It seems `data.table` does not recognize `..` once it's wrapped inside another function in `j`. I know I can use `sum(get(var))` to achieve the results but I want to know I am using the best practice in most situation.

Comment: I think it's part of the idea for this open issue https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/633

Comment: But `dt[, sum('x')]` would still throw an error either way, even if `..var` was found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parroting [an answer to a different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234064/getx-does-not-work-in-r-data-table-when-x-is-also-a-column-in-the-data-table/48592048#48592048) that works here as well. Not the prettiest solution, but variants on this have worked for me numerous times in the past.

Thanks @Frank for a non-`parse()` solution here!

<strike>I'm well familiar with the old adage *"If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question."*, but I have a hard time coming up with alternatives many times when evaluating within the `data.table` calling environment, I'd love to see a robust solution that doesn't execute arbitrary code passed in as a character string. **In fact, half the reason I'm posting an answer like this is in hopes that someone can recommend a better option.**</strike>

```
test_func3 <- function(data, var, var2) {
  expr = substitute(sum(var), list(var=as.symbol(var)))
  data[, eval(expr)]
}

test_func3(dt, 'x', 'y')
## [1] 5.472968
```

**Quick disclaimer on hypothetical doomsday scenarios possible with eval(parse(...))**

There are far more [in depth discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse) on the dangers of `eval(parse(...))`, but I'll avoid repeating them in full.

Theoretically you could have issues if one of your columns is named something unfortunate like `"(system(paste0('kill ',Sys.getpid())))"` *(Do not execute that, it will kill your R session on the spot!).* This is probably enough of an outside chance to not lose sleep over it unless you plan on putting this in a package on CRAN.

---

#### Update:

For the specific case in the comments below where the table is grouped and then `sum` is applied to all, `.SDcols` is potentially useful. The only way I'm aware of to make sure that this function would return consistent results even if `dt` had a column named `var3` is to evaluate the arguments within the function environment but outside of the `data.table` environment using `c()`.

```
set.seed(42)
dt <- data.table(
  x = rnorm(10),
  y = rnorm(10),
  z = sample(c("a","b","c"),size = 10, replace = TRUE)
)


test_func3 <- function(data, var, var2, var3) {
  ListOfColumns = c(var,var2)
  GroupColumn <- c(var3)
  dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by= eval(GroupColumn), .SDcols = ListOfColumns]
}

test_func3(dt, 'x', 'y','z')
```

returns

```
   z         x         y
1: b 1.0531555  2.121852
2: a 0.3631284 -1.388861
3: c 4.0566838 -2.367558
```

Comment: Or `sum(data[[var]])` at least for the OP's example.

Comment: @Frank that is a better solution for this simplistic use case, but I'm not sure it can be generalized to more complex cases, like grouping by `var2` in that function. Would you have any recommendations on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234064/getx-does-not-work-in-r-data-table-when-x-is-also-a-column-in-the-data-table)?

Comment: @MattSummersgill, that's what I am trying to accomplish, `sum(var), sum(var2), group by var3`, and I want to return the results as a data.table. Right now I am using `data[, .(sum(get(var)), sum(get(var2)), by = var3]`

Comment: @MattSummersgill, thanks! this is a very good solution. I also found that you could use `by = var3` directly without using `c()`. I am still hoping there's a `..` solution.